power supply for magnetic vise
Using a microwave transformer for a magnetic vise, I am needing a power supply.
Experimenting with a 12 volt DC 5 amp Automotive battery charger, the magnetic vise seems to work well.
So, for a permanent power supply... I tried using a manufactured switching power supply, rated at 120 AC volt in, and 12-volt DC, 10 amp output. It has poor magnetic results.                     Any idea's why this AC to DC switching power supply is-not working as well as the Battery charger?

Did you measure the charger output voltage? It may be far above 12 V.

What Jens said,... A charger that is designed for a nominally 12V battery is not the same thing as a 12V constant voltage supply. A "smart" battery charger will go through a sequence of constant current, constant voltage, and possibly other modes when it is hooked up to a battery and switched on.

The voltage of a battery charger is higher than that of a 12-volt power supply. Typically, a 12-volt power supply delivers around 12 to 12.6 volts. However, a 12-volt battery charger provides a higher voltage, from 13.8 volts in Float mode to 14.4 volts in Bulk mode. Less expensive car battery chargers often work in a single mode, providing a constant-current constant-voltage (CC/CV) charge of 14.4 volts up to the charger's maximum rated current.
Your volt meter knows the answer.
